# Measure total time spent by a process on IO

Tags: linux, performance, io

While running time command, one of the programs gives following output:

```
real    1m33.523s
user    0m15.156s
sys 0m1.312s
```

Here the real and user+sys time have a lot of difference. This is most likely due to time spent on IO wait/calls. I want to measure total time spend by program in IO wait or IO calls. Is there any way to do that?

I tried using iotop. However, it doesnot report total time spent by the program performing IO.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `strace` - which can provide per-system-call statistics.

**Example 1**

I want to measure time spent on I/O while accessing stackoverflow.com:

```
$ time  curl stackoverflow.com >/dev/null 2>&1
curl stackoverflow.com > /dev/null 2>&1  0.00s user 0.01s system 2% cpu 0.392 total
```

OK, 2% CPU and 0.01 s in system. Let's find out:

```
$ strace -c curl stackoverflow.com >/dev/null 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  240k    0  240k    0     0   127k      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  130k
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 54.12    0.005497          11       506           write
 18.16    0.001845          43        43           fstat
 11.95    0.001214          30        41           poll
  5.75    0.000584          32        18           recvfrom
  3.40    0.000345           3       101           mmap
  2.51    0.000255           4        62           mprotect
  1.98    0.000201           4        50           close
  1.84    0.000187          31         6           getsockname
  0.29    0.000029           1        42         1 open
```

Especially useful compare this results with results measured for runing `curl` without args.

Anyway. strace shows that curl mostly spends time in write, fstat and poll.

**Another example**

The first approach seems show incorrect results for sleep. If you are not satisfied with the first approach you can just print get times of each syscall (`strace -T`). Get this data and process them to find summary time of each syscall.

```
$ strace 2>&1 -T curl stackoverflow.com >/dev/null | head -n 20

execve("/usr/bin/curl", ["curl", "stackoverflow.com"], [/* 62 vars */]) = 0 <0.000219>
brk(0)                                  = 0x186e000 <0.000175>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc04c9e6000 <0.000166>
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000238>
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3 <0.000144>
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=96498, ...}) = 0 <0.000175>
mmap(NULL, 96498, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc04c9ce000 <0.000164>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000160>
open("/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000047>
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\333\300\">\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 <0.000160>
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=346008, ...}) = 0 <0.000216>
mmap(0x3e22c00000, 2438600, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3e22c00000 <0.000189>
mprotect(0x3e22c51000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0 <0.000032>
mmap(0x3e22e51000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x51000) = 0x3e22e51000 <0.000119>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000110>
open("/lib64/libidn.so.11", O_RDONLY)   = 3 <0.000257>
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0/@U1\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 <0.000051>
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=209088, ...}) = 0 <0.000041>
mmap(0x3155400000, 2301736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3155400000 <0.000037>
mprotect(0x3155432000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 <0.000037>
```

Comment: For the command I used, strace gives 0.082841s as total time spend in system calls (other time measurement in qn itself). I want to measure time spend in iowait too.